# How to create a folder in an amazon S3 bucket using CDK for amplify upload requirement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I have created a s3 bucket with CDK

```
const test_bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'assets-bucket-id', {
  bucketName: 'assets-bucket-name',
  cors: [
    {
      allowedHeaders: [
        "*"
      ],
      allowedMethods: [
        s3.HttpMethods.POST,
        s3.HttpMethods.PUT,
        s3.HttpMethods.GET,
      ],
      allowedOrigins: [
        "*"
      ],
      exposedHeaders: [
        'x-amz-server-side-encryption',
        'x-amz-request-id',
        'x-amz-id-2',
        'ETag'
      ],
    }
  ],
})
```

however i want to add folders of `protected`, `public`, `private` since i m using that for cognito uploads and those are required https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js/

is there anyway i can use cdk s3 module to achieve that?

thanks

Comment: S3 is a flat object store, not a filesystem with directories (although a lot of frontends display it like a filesystem). "Folders" can not exist unless they contain a file, similar to how `git` works.

Comment: @jordanm you can create a zero-sized object whose key ends in your folder delimiter, e.g. `countries/spain/` and it will represent a folder to clients. This is what the S3 console does when you ask it to create a folder.

Comment: @jarmod does that mean only via lambda creation? I had a thought to create a lambda with cdk upon creation which triggered to create the file with folder. however i want to explore if there's any way that without going with lambda

Comment: You probably don't need to create these 'folder' objects at all. They don't need to exist for your app to be able to write to `protected/myid/cat.png`, for example. If you find that you do need them, which I doubt, you can use any S3 client code (running in Lambda, EC2, via awscli, etc.)

Comment: you are totally right @jarmod! i tried with Storage.configure with the desired level (e.g. 'protected') https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js/ and it automatically create a folder as the level upon successful upload, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what @Jarmod clarified in comments, even though it's possible to use Lambda or some scripts to automate creation of folders upon resource creation by CDK (CDK has no native way of doing it at the time being), it's not needed for my use case.

The respective folders will be created upon successful upload.

Tested by configuring to specify desired 'level' (e.g. 'protected') docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/configureaccess/q/platform/js and it automatically create a folder as the level upon successful upload.

Comment: To be clear, it almost certainly did not actually create any folders. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69623164/271415) for more explanation about S3 and folders and why you don't typically need folders.

Answer (score 0):

I created [this Custom Resource](https://github.com/san99tiago/aws-cdk-multiple-experiments/tree/main/custom_resource_s3_folders) to solve the problem, as I needed the "folders" pre-created for an AWS Transfer Family SFTP Server, even though "folders" do not exist in S3 technically.

The solution is in AWS-CDK-Python, but concepts should be easily migrated to AWS-CDK-TypeScript if needed.

- Lambda Handler: https://github.com/san99tiago/aws-cdk-multiple-experiments/blob/main/custom_resource_s3_folders/simple_solution/src/create_folders_s3.py
- CDK Code: https://github.com/san99tiago/aws-cdk-multiple-experiments/blob/main/custom_resource_s3_folders/stacks/s3_example_stack.py

The implementation works as expected for the new folder(s), and it also doesn't delete the existing S3 keys inside the "folder" (which is one of the limitations of the "aws_s3_deployment" CDK Constuct from AWS as of now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).